# Extracting Index from an Array, that contains each word in the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Sorry if the title is a bit misleading and inaccurate, but ... didnt know how else to title the problem.
So here is it(the Problem) described in details.

How do I create a function that :

- takes 2 parameters:

  1. -a String
  2. -and an array that consists each word in that string
- and returns the indexes of the decomposed string

*an element in this array can contain/have more then one word in it
(i.e. "Grey Dog")

let me show you what I mean by showing the string, the array and the desired output:

```
var animals = [
"Grey Dog",           //0
"Lion",               //1
"2 Cats",             //2
"Black Widow Spider", //3
"Hippo",              //4
"Bird"                //5
]

var userInputText = "2 Cats Hippo Grey Dog Lion Hippo Lion 2 Cats Black Widow Spider Hippo Hippo";


var output = decomposeStringToIndexes(animals ,userInputText);
```

and when I trace / log / check the **output** variable, it will contain:

```
output = [
2,//2 Cats
4,//Hippo
0,//Grey Dog
1,//Lion
4,//Hippo
1,//Lion
2,//2 Cats
3,//Black Widow Spider
4,//Hippo
4//Hippo
];
```

EDIT:

- the string (userInputText) will only contain words that are listed in the array(animals)
- there can be more than one white space (i.e. ' ') in between each
  word

something like this :

```
var userInputText = "2 Cats      Hippo    Grey Dog    Lion   Hippo     Lion 2 Cats Black Widow Spider       Hippo  Hippo";
```

Comment: What ahve you tried so far?

Comment: What decomposeStringToIndexes function is doing exactly?

Comment: first to create an array *wordsArray* by splitting the words by white spaces, and then to check if the current word in the *wordsArray* is the same as some of the words in the *animals* array. if not, then check if this element(i) and the next(i+1) could create a string that is contained in the *animals*.

Hope you understand me.

Comment: but.... then there is the part that the user can input unlimited white spaces in between the words, like "Grey Dog            2 Cats        Hippo       2 Cats       "
and ... from there I dont know how to figure it out

Comment: it is converting  *userInputText* by  splicing the string into peaces that need to match an element from the *animals* array @Sandip Nirmal

Comment: Can you try by checking indexOf, if index is > -1 increment count for particular string. Then create substring from new index and search in substring. You need to do it recursively till you are getting indexOf > -1 or end of string. Let me try it.

Comment: The key task here is to split the string into several parts, it can't be done in common way. You need to provide some additional array of key items.

Comment: What if `animals = [”Grey Dog", "Grey", "Dog"]`?

Comment: well Im at the point where I get the text and use * .split(" ").filter(Boolean) *  now I guess what I need to do is what  Sandip Nirmal said

Comment: @Max Zuber are you suggesting an array of arrays ? like [  ["Hippo"], ["Grey", "Dog" ], ["Bird"]    ] 
and checking if the current word is contained in on of those innder arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to iterate over the search words and remember the position and build an object with these items. Later strip the indices and return just an array.

> `~` is a [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It is perfect for use with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), because `indexOf` returns if found the index `0 ... n` and if not `-1`:
>
> ```
> value  ~value   boolean
>  -1  =>   0  =>  false
>   0  =>  -1  =>  true
>   1  =>  -2  =>  true
>   2  =>  -3  =>  true
>   and so on
> ```

```js
function decomposeStringToIndexes(array, string) {
    var found = {};
    array.forEach(function (a, i) {
        var p = 0,
            pos = string.indexOf(a);
        while (~pos) { // equal to pos !== -1
            found[pos] = i;
            p = pos + a.length;
            pos = string.indexOf(a, p);
        }
    });
    return Object.keys(found)
        .map(Number)
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })
        .map(function (k) { return found[k]; });
};

var animals = ["Grey Dog", "Lion", "2 Cats", "Black Widow Spider", "Hippo", "Bird"],
    userInputText = "2 Cats Hippo Grey Dog Lion Hippo Lion 2 Cats Black Widow Spider Hippo Hippo",
    output = decomposeStringToIndexes(animals, userInputText);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: It does what I want : D, but I dont fully understand how it does it. Can I ask what does the *while (~pos)* mean ?

Comment: I did, I did. Thank you a lot : ). I didnt think that I would get such a descriptively answer.